# remove service oriented architecture by configuration

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, soa

I will develop a layered application. It will contain DataAccessLayer, ModelLayer, BusinessLayer, WCF Service Layer and Presentation Layer. I want to write all business logic code in BusinessLayer and just service them from WCF. But in some cases i may want to disable all WCF layer and call BusinessLayer Functions from ASP.NET presentation layer. I want to be able to do this by a little configuration. I will use Dependency injection in my layers with Ninject. I will also develop a proxy creator for calling WCF.

Is there a pattern for this or how can i do it with a good structure.

Thanks

Comment: By service proxy creator i mean a dynamic proxy class to call wcf

Comment: So the WCF layer is a decorator of the business layer? Then you can just create the decorator stack based on the configuration and access it just via its interface.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95). It shows how to design your system around messages (commands and queries) and how to maintainebly expose them through WCF. This design allows removing the transport layer completely without much effort and without both the PL and BL to know anything about this change.

Comment: I can split the interfaces layer to decorate WCF, interface layer can also decorate business layer both of them